# ORACLE - After trigger is not passing the value to the procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a problem with a "after insert" trigger which won't pass the value to a stored procedure that i'm calling inside the trigger.
It works ok for update and also i should mention that i am querying the table in the procedure that i am calling.
It goes something like:

```
create or replace trigger test_trg
after insert or update on table1
for each row
begin
    test_procedure(:new.value1);
end;
```

The procedure looks inside table1 and inserts in table2 hints about what should be added in table1 based on the current inserted/updated row.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: We cannot debug code we cannot see. Please post the source of the called procedure, with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger transaction is depend on its statement transaction. Therefore you can not read uncommitted records. So you should transfer "test_procedure" codes into your trigger and  use :New record values to insert data into table2.
Your code should look like this:

```
create or replace trigger test_trg
after insert or update on table1
for each row
begin
    if inserting then
      insert into table2(ID, F1, F2, ...)
      values (NEW_ID_VALUE, :NEW.F1_VALUE, :NEW.F2_VALUE, ...);
    elsif updating then
      update table2
      set  F1 = :NEW.F1_VALUE
         , F2 = :NEW.F2_VALUE
      where TABLE1_ID_FK = :NEW.ID;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @BarbarosÖzhan.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
That would be a very big and rather messy trigger, but it just might work. 
I think i`ll go with it if nothing else pops into mind.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
The problem was not the trigger, it was in the procedure. I was performing a "dirty read" based on the record ID that i was sending (the record id of a new row).
Even though my trigger is "after insert" it looks like my row can't be found by the procedure and i was basing all my operations on it.

Fixed it by adding more parameters to the procedure and passing :new values straight from the trigger for everything i needed.